# Proxy a private interface

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm in a situation where I really need to proxy a private inner java interface of a class with a protected constructor.

I'm stuck with existing compiled java code:

```java
public class Foo {

  Foo() {}

  private interface Bar {
    void someMethod();
  }
}
```

And trying to write this clojure code:

```clj
(proxy [Foo$Bar] []
  (someMethod []
     ...))
```

But compiling this throws `java.lang.IllegalAccessError "proxy... cannot access its superinterface Foo$Bar"`.

Is there some incantation that can get around this?  I'd be happy to use whatever dirty tricks are necessary.

Comment: Very interesting question.  I thought I new the answer but it turned out to be a different solution than I expected.  :)

Comment: Can you say more about why you need to do this? A private interface is an implementation detail of the enclosing class, so I don’t think you would be able to use your proxy to interface with existing code in any way.

Comment: Sure, I have an application that must override java.net.InetAddress's name resolution logic.  On JDK8, I can proxy sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService and use reflection to set InetAddress.nameServices to my own implementation of the NameService.  I'm updating this application to JDK10 and they made the NameService interface a private inner interface of java.net.InetAddress.  (I realize they also provide a hosts file option, but the name resolution logic I need is not expressable in a hosts file).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to `extend` the original class, and copy the interface while marking it as `public` access:

```
package demo;
public class Calc {
  Calc() {
    System.out.println(  "Calc() constructor");
  }
  private interface Adder {
    String doSomething();
  }
}
```

with the new child class:

```
package demo;
public class CalcChild extends Calc {
  public CalcChild() {
    super();
    System.out.println("CalcChild(): super() - return ");
  }
  public interface Adder {
    String doSomething();
  }
  public void doBoo() {
    System.out.println("Boo!");
  }
}
```

And the `proxy` code:

```
 (let [adder      (proxy [demo.CalcChild$Adder] []
                    (doSomething [] "something"))
       calcChild  (demo.CalcChild.)]
   (.doSomething adder)
   (.doBoo calcChild))
```

with result:

```
Calc() constructor
CalcChild(): super() - return 
(.doSomething adder) => "something"
Boo!
```

---

***Update:***

I Updated the answer, but something is still not right.  Even if I comment out the new `CalcChild()` constructor, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: What a creative idea.  I tried it, but realized that I forgot to specify in my original question that Foo also has a protected constructor, so when I try to extend it, I get "Foo() is not public in Foo; cannot be accessed from outside package" :-(.  I will update the question.

Comment: OK I think I see what's going on.  I think your sample code works because Calc and CalcChild are both in the same package.  I unfortunately don't have access to the package containing the class I would be extending.  And this is jdk10 so if I try to recreate the same package hierarchy, I get "error: package exists in another module".